# How to get all order details in wordpress/woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I am using woo-commerce and trying to get all the order details from database.I am new to it and cant make it happened.I have already created `order_details.php` template where I can get all orders data.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 8):

Try This Code.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'shop_order',
 'posts_per_page' => '-1'
);
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);

$orders = $my_query->posts;
echo "</pre>";
print_r($orders);
echo "<pre>";
```

Customize As par Ur Requerment.

Comment: Thanks for your step.But unfortunately it returns a blank array.Let me explain you I have woocommerce installed in my localhost and there are 2 orders in it.All I need to get those order details from database.Will you please let me know how to get all those data. @Dev Danidhariya

Comment: 'global $woocommerce;'

Add Top in my code.and check.

Comment: hello solve Your Proble or not.

Comment: Not yet bro. :( trying to modify a plugin to export CSV of order details.

Comment: Just add 'post_status' => 'all' and it will return all orders

Comment: found this because i was looking for how, if u want get only completed like for sync with ur controlling app use  'post_status' => 'wc-completed'

Answer (score 8):

Since Woocommerce mega major Update 3.0+ things have changed quite a lot:

- WC_Order properties can't be access directly as before and will throw some errors.
- New **WC_Order** and **WC_Abstract_Order** getters and setters methods are now needed.
- There is some New classes for Order items:

  - WC_Order_Item class.
  - WC_Order_Item_Product class.

So also the Order items properties will not be accessible as before in a foreach loop and you will have to use [this specific getter and setter methods](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order_Item_Product.html) instead

```
// Get an instance of the WC_Order object (same as before)
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

// Get the order ID
$order_id = $order->get_id();

// Get the custumer ID
$order_id = $order->get_user_id();
```

Get and access to the order data properties (in an array of values):

```
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

$order_data = $order->get_data(); // The Order data

$order_id = $order_data['id'];
$order_parent_id = $order_data['parent_id'];
$order_status = $order_data['status'];
$order_currency = $order_data['currency'];
$order_version = $order_data['version'];
$order_payment_method = $order_data['payment_method'];
$order_payment_method_title = $order_data['payment_method_title'];
$order_payment_method = $order_data['payment_method'];
$order_payment_method = $order_data['payment_method'];

## Creation and modified WC_DateTime Object date string ##

// Using a formated date ( with php date() function as method)
$order_date_created = $order_data['date_created']->date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$order_date_modified = $order_data['date_modified']->date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

// Using a timestamp ( with php getTimestamp() function as method)
$order_timestamp_created = $order_data['date_created']->getTimestamp();
$order_timestamp_modified = $order_data['date_modified']->getTimestamp();


$order_discount_total = $order_data['discount_total'];
$order_discount_tax = $order_data['discount_tax'];
$order_shipping_total = $order_data['shipping_total'];
$order_shipping_tax = $order_data['shipping_tax'];
$order_total = $order_data['cart_tax'];
$order_total_tax = $order_data['total_tax'];
$order_customer_id = $order_data['customer_id']; // ... and so on

## BILLING INFORMATION:

$order_billing_first_name = $order_data['billing']['first_name'];
$order_billing_last_name = $order_data['billing']['last_name'];
$order_billing_company = $order_data['billing']['company'];
$order_billing_address_1 = $order_data['billing']['address_1'];
$order_billing_address_2 = $order_data['billing']['address_2'];
$order_billing_city = $order_data['billing']['city'];
$order_billing_state = $order_data['billing']['state'];
$order_billing_postcode = $order_data['billing']['postcode'];
$order_billing_country = $order_data['billing']['country'];
$order_billing_email = $order_data['billing']['email'];
$order_billing_phone = $order_data['billing']['phone'];

## SHIPPING INFORMATION:

$order_shipping_first_name = $order_data['shipping']['first_name'];
$order_shipping_last_name = $order_data['shipping']['last_name'];
$order_shipping_company = $order_data['shipping']['company'];
$order_shipping_address_1 = $order_data['shipping']['address_1'];
$order_shipping_address_2 = $order_data['shipping']['address_2'];
$order_shipping_city = $order_data['shipping']['city'];
$order_shipping_state = $order_data['shipping']['state'];
$order_shipping_postcode = $order_data['shipping']['postcode'];
$order_shipping_country = $order_data['shipping']['country'];
```

Get the order items and access the data with WC_Order_Item_Product and WC_Order_Item methods:

```
$order = wc_get_order($order_id);

// Iterating through each WC_Order_Item_Product objects
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_key => $item_values):

    ## Using WC_Order_Item methods ##

    // Item ID is directly accessible from the $item_key in the foreach loop or
    $item_id = $item_values->get_id();

    ## Using WC_Order_Item_Product methods ##

    $item_name = $item_values->get_name(); // Name of the product
    $item_type = $item_values->get_type(); // Type of the order item ("line_item")

    $product_id = $item_values->get_product_id(); // the Product id
    $wc_product = $item_values->get_product(); // the WC_Product object
    ## Access Order Items data properties (in an array of values) ##
    $item_data = $item_values->get_data();

    $product_name = $item_data['name'];
    $product_id = $item_data['product_id'];
    $variation_id = $item_data['variation_id'];
    $quantity = $item_data['quantity'];
    $tax_class = $item_data['tax_class'];
    $line_subtotal = $item_data['subtotal'];
    $line_subtotal_tax = $item_data['subtotal_tax'];
    $line_total = $item_data['total'];
    $line_total_tax = $item_data['total_tax'];

endforeach;
```

Answer (score 6):

`$my_course_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'shop_order','post_status'=>'wc-completed'));`

Change status to woocoommerce status

Comment: PErfectionzzz! Thanks

Comment: Too much oooo in there

Answer (score 1):

You can user below code

```
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php');

global $wpdb;

    $orders = get_posts( array(
        'post_type'   => 'shop_order',
        'posts_per_page' => '-1'
) );
```

You need to include `wp-load.php` file

```
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php');
```

and add global variable as `global $wpdb;` before this code.